# PyO3-Maturin publish command doesn't upload Readme and License to PyPi

Tags: python, rust, pypi, readme, pyo3

I've a built a rust-python project and published it to PyPi using Maturin.
The project is structured like the example on the maturin readme with the addition of the License  file:

```
my_project
├── Cargo.toml
├── my_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── bar.py
├── Readme.md
├── LICENSE
└── src
    └── lib.rs
```

When I use `maturin publish` the readme and license files aren't uploaded to pypi.

I'd like to also publish the readme and license files on PyPi and can't find any info on how to do that using maturin, or just separately add the missing files to PyPi...

I would appreciate any info on how to get the readme and license files to PyPi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty late to the party, but for future reference, you can include these files in the source distribution when using `maturin`, by adding the following to `pyproject.toml`.

```ini
[tool.maturin]
sdist-include = ["LICENSE", "Readme.md"]
```

I see that you don't have a `pyproject.toml` in yours, not sure if this is due to an older version of maturin or what, but that's the up-to-date way at least.

Comment: Better late than never ;)